# How to filter AWS logs for Lambda to see just console.logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, grep, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently using `aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/lambda-name --region us-east-1` to get logs from a lambda, but the logs that come back are quite.... extensive. 
For example:

```
{
  "ingestionTime": *, 
  "timestamp": *, 
  "message": "START RequestId: * Version: $LATEST\n", 
  "eventId": "*", 
  "logStreamName": "2018/10/26/[$LATEST]*"
}...
```

Can I get just the messages out with only a bash command that fits in the npm script? Maybe with grep or find.

Comment: Have you tried piping it into jq and picking the specific attribute in the Json object yet? Also that command doesn't output the logs in order.

Comment: That's right! I read that and forgot that it doesn't order them. I forget what was troubling about the other command. I have two use cases. One is tailing the logs, and the other is getting the logs for the last few days. Getting the logs for the last few days is rare so I can always log into the AWS console, but tailing I have to do often, and there's no way to do it natively in the AWS tools.

Comment: what about the put-subscription-filter command? That should provide a real-time tail of the logs to another AWS Lambda function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-subscription-filter.html

> Subscription filters allow you to subscribe to a real-time stream of log events ingested through PutLogEvents and have them delivered to a specific destination

Comment: looks like there's an example lambda function here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the specific attributes in the logs returned by the [filter-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html) command you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/). Here is an example that I did in windows powershell.

`aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name <yourLogGroup> --region <yourRegion> | jq '.events[].message'`

There is also a `--filter-pattern` parameter which there are some examples for [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#w2aac13c11b9c28b6b6b6)

If the command needs to get the last few days it can use the `--start-time` and `--end-time` parameters of the filter-log-events command.

To have a real time subscription of the CloudWatch logs, the project can use the [put-subscription-filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-subscription-filter.html) command to write the logs to another Lambda function to process them. Here is an example function in nodejs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    var payload = new Buffer(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(e, result) {
        if (e) { 
            context.fail(e);
        } else {
            result = JSON.parse(result.toString('ascii'));
            console.log("Event Data:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```